# GLWF capturing mouse leads to a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl

For an opengl veteran this is probably easy, but I am completely new to opengl and I am currently working through a tutorial.

I am now at the point where it is about to capture mouse events (to setup camera movement).

However, although I am running the original code from the author, I am getting a segmentation fault.

I guess he probably forget to set something additional up (just a guess).

But, since I am an absolute opengl beginner, I am completely lost what this could be.

The problem is that capturing the mouse movement yields a segmentation fault.

The mouse and keyboard input is completely capsuled in a separate class called `Window.cpp`.

I will post the complete code since I do not know where to start:

Window.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

#include </usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.1.0_1/include/GL/glew.h>
#include </usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/include/GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Window
{
    public:
        Window();
        Window(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight);

        int initialize();
        GLint getBufferWidth() { return bufferWidth; }
        GLint getBufferHeight() { return bufferHeight; }

        bool getShouldClose() { return glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow); }

        bool* getKeys() { return keys; };
        GLfloat getXChange();
        GLfloat getYChange();

        void swapBuffer() { glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow); }

        ~Window();

    private:
        GLFWwindow *mainWindow;

        GLint width, height;
        GLint bufferWidth, bufferHeight;

        bool keys[1024];

        GLfloat lastX, lastY, xChange, yChange;
        bool mouseFirstMoved;

        void createCallBacks();
        static void handleKeys(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int code, int action, int mode);
        static void handleMouse(GLFWwindow* window, double xPos, double yPos);
};
```

And its implementation Window.cpp:

```
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window() {
    width=800;
    height=600;

    xChange = 0.0f;
    yChange = 0.0f;
    mouseFirstMoved = false;

    for(size_t  i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
        keys[i] = 0;
}

Window::Window(GLint windowWidth, GLint windowHeight) {
    width = windowWidth;
    height = windowHeight;
}

int Window::initialize() {
    //Initialize GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() ) {
        printf("GLFW initialization failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    //Setup GLFW window properties
    // OpenGL Version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    //Core profile means no backwards compatibility for OpenGL minor to 3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //Make this code compatible for later version for OpenGL 3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "1st OpenGL Project Window", NULL, NULL);
    if(!mainWindow) {
        printf("GLFWwindow creation failed");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    //Get buffer size information
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);

    //set context for GLEW to use
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    //handle key and mouse input
    createCallBacks();
    glfwSetInputMode(mainWindow, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    //Allow modern extension features
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        printf("GLEW initilization failed");
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    //Video 15: enable depth buffer to order the triangles of the pyramid
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Set viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(mainWindow, this);
    return 0;
}


void Window::createCallBacks() {
    glfwSetKeyCallback(mainWindow, handleKeys);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(mainWindow, handleMouse);
}


GLfloat Window::getXChange() {
    GLfloat theChange = xChange;
    xChange = 0.0f;
    return theChange;
}

GLfloat Window::getYChange() {
    GLfloat theChange = yChange;
    yChange = 0.0f;
    return theChange;
}

void Window::handleKeys(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int code, int action, int mode) {
    Window* theWindow = static_cast<Window*> (glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    if( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }


    if( 0<= key && key < 1024 ) {
        if(action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            theWindow->keys[key] = true;
        } else if(action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
            theWindow->keys[key] = false;
        }
    }

}

void Window::handleMouse(GLFWwindow* window, double xPos, double yPos) {
    Window* theWindow = static_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));

    if (theWindow->mouseFirstMoved)
    {
        theWindow->lastX = xPos;
        theWindow->lastY = yPos;
        theWindow->mouseFirstMoved = false;
    }

    theWindow->xChange = xPos - theWindow->lastX;
    theWindow->yChange = theWindow->lastY - yPos;

    theWindow->lastX = xPos;
    theWindow->lastY = yPos;
}


Window::~Window() {
    glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

The window loads and opens.

But as soon as I move the mouse only slightly the program crashes and I get a segmentation fault.

This is the output:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

However, pressing the ESCAPE button closes the window correctly as you would expect from this code.

I am lost so any advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and see which line causes the failure? Without that, I'm guessing the most likely culprit is the user pointer not being set yet when the first mouse event appears.

Comment: Could you post your main loop please? You should have a loop somewhere where you call `glfwPollEvents()`, typically at the beginning or the end of your update/render mechanism.

Comment: You call `createCallBacks` before `glfwSetWindowUserPointer`. But `handleMouse` relies on the user pointer being set.